# Datatable searching the clicked element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have used datatable for a table.

```
$('#tableid').dataTable({
  "aLengthMenu": [
    [2, 5, 7, -1],
    [2, 5, 7, "All"]
  ],
  "iDisplayLength": 5
});
```

and I if click on any div element I want the value of the div element to be searched in the datatable.e.g.

```
<div id="search>
  <a href="">this</a>
</div>
```

If I click on this, 'this' to be searched in the table.How can this be achieved?

```
$(document).on('click','#search',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var search=$('#search').val();

}
```

Comment: What is the datatables version that you are using?

Comment: version1.10.12 it is. @palaѕн

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use search() function for datatable to search manually

```
<script>
        var table = $('#tableid').dataTable({
          "aLengthMenu": [
            [2, 5, 7, -1],
            [2, 5, 7, "All"]
          ],
          "iDisplayLength": 5
        });

$(document).on('click','#search',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var search =$('#search').text();
        table.search(search).draw();
    }   
</script>

     <div id="search>

     </div>
```

Comment: @Steve, because you have initialised with `dataTable()`, use `DataTable()` instead - if you _need_ the jQuery object you can use `table.api().search()` ...

Comment: @davidkonrad how can i make it work for dynamic texts. `<?php foreach($categories as $category):?><div id="search"><a href=""><?php echo $category->category;?></a></div><?php endforeach;?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({// or .dataTable({ for version under 1.10
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [2, 5, 7, -1],
                [2, 5, 7, "All"]
            ],
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        });
        // it is more efficient to bind the click event not on body rather only on the needed elements
        // you can use class name for selector if you want to use it on more divs
        $('.search').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            // you need to trim the given value because it can contain whitespace characters which can result false filtering
            var search = $.trim($(this).text());
            table.search(search).draw();
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="search">
  <a href="#">this</a>
</div>
<div class="search">
    <a href="#">that</a>
</div>
```